# OpenCV checks the size of the object through the image Python

Tags: python, opencv

Hello I wrote a software to check the size of the object in the image, it works fine but can't check the small size object?

This is my code, please help

```
import cv2
from object_detector import *
import numpy as np

detector = HomogeneousBgDetector()

img = cv2.imread("check.png")

contours = detector.detect_objects(img)

for cnt in contours:
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
    (x, y), (w, h), angle = rect

    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)

    cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    cv2.polylines(img, [box], True, (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(img, "Width {} cm".format(round(w, 1)), (int(x - 100), int(y - 20)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (100, 200, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(img, "Height {} cm".format(round(h, 1)), (int(x - 100), int(y + 15)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (100, 200, 0), 2)



cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

file object_detector.py

```
import cv2


class HomogeneousBgDetector():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def detect_objects(self, frame):
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        mask = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 19, 5)

        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        objects_contours = []

        for cnt in contours:
            area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
            if area > 2000:
                objects_contours.append(cnt)

        return objects_contours
```

Image I want to check: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym7aH.png)

Result I got: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5sDv.png)

Result I want to get: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q01L6.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to reduce your value where you are checking for a minimum area to detect the object in detect_objects method

```
  for cnt in contours:
      area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
      if area > 500:
          objects_contours.append(cnt)
```

The value 500 for the area would be a perfect minimum area value for the object in your case. I have attached the result of giving the value as 500 [image]

Comment: do you know any way to check object only by rgb color code?